# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to implement search functionality among lists of banks in my app.
So somehow I need to use stringResId() but you can't call it without composable func(). Also by using Resources.getSystem().getString() is giving me resources not found exception.

This is my viewModel code

```
class BankViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private val _bankAccount = MutableStateFlow(BankAccount())
    val bankAccount: StateFlow<BankAccount> = _bankAccount.asStateFlow()

    var bankList = mutableStateOf(Banks)

    private var cachedBankList = listOf<Bank>()
    private var isSearchStarting = true
    var isSearching = mutableStateOf(false)

    fun updateBankSearch(searchName: String) {
        _bankAccount.update { bankAccount ->
            bankAccount.copy(bankName = searchName)
        }
    }
    fun searchBankName(query: String) {
        val listToSearch = if(isSearchStarting) {
            bankList.value
        }else {
            cachedBankList
        }
        viewModelScope.launch {
            if (query.isEmpty()) {
                bankList.value = cachedBankList
                isSearching.value = false
                isSearchStarting = true
                return@launch
            }
            val results = listToSearch.filter {
                Resources.getSystem().getString(it.bankName).contains(query.trim(), ignoreCase = true)
            }
            if (isSearchStarting) {
                cachedBankList = bankList.value
                isSearchStarting = false
            }
            bankList.value = results
            isSearching.value = true
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Bank

```
data class Bank (
        @StringRes val bankName: Int,
        @DrawableRes val bankLogo: Int = R.drawable.bank_image_2
        )
```

So my question is how can I get a string by using id so that I can compare it with the query??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `Application` `Context` to retrieve resources like these.

If you're not using any DI framework, or you don't want to use custom `ViewModelProvider.Factory`, extend `AndroidViewModel` (which holds a reference to `Application`) instead of regular `ViewModel`.

Ideally ViewModels shouldn't contain any Android-specific objects, and you would use some custom `StringProvider`, or something similar, but that's not a topic of your question.

Comment: Please tell me exactly what I have to do? How to use custom StringProvider or something similar??

Comment: The easiest solution for you would be to extend `AndroidViewModel` instead of `ViewModel`, and use the `application` property.

Comment: Thanks for this. It works for me. I have extended `AndroidViewModel` instead of `ViewModel`, I have used the following 
`getApplication<Application>().getString(it.bankName).contains(query.trim(), ignoreCase = true)`
It works fine for me but any further suggestions from your side is accepted.